# How to migrate same class with 2 entity-names to Spring Data JPA?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I am migrating an app to Spring Data JPA from Hibernate. I already migrated a few repositories and have that working. I now have a special case I need to convert.

I have this in my .hbm.xml:

```
<class name="SoundNotification" table="SoundNotification" entity-name="SoundNotificationWithData">
        <id name="m_id" type="int" column="id" unsaved-value="-1">
            <generator class="native"/>
        </id>
        <property name="m_name" column="name" unique="true" not-null="true"/>
        <property name="m_data" column="data"
                  type="com.traficon.tmsng.server.common.service.persistence.impl.hibernate.usertype.BlobUserType"
                  not-null="true"/>
        <property name="m_size" formula="OCTET_LENGTH(data)"/>
        <property name="m_inUse"
                  formula="(select count(1) from EventTypeConfiguration etc where etc.soundNotification=id)"/>
    </class>

    <class name="SoundNotification" table="SoundNotification" entity-name="SoundNotificationWithoutData">
        <id name="m_id" type="int" column="id" unsaved-value="-1">
            <generator class="native"/>
        </id>
        <property name="m_name" column="name" unique="true" not-null="true"/>
        <property name="m_size" formula="OCTET_LENGTH(data)"/>
        <property name="m_inUse"
                  formula="(select count(1) from EventTypeConfiguration etc where etc.soundNotification=id)"/>
    </class>
```

Notice how I only have 1 class `SoundNotification`, but it is used with 2 different `entity-name`s (SoundNotificationWithData and SoundNotificationWithoutData)

Is it possible to convert this to Spring Data JPA? Would I need to create 2 java classes as a "workaround" ?

Another example which we have is this one:

```
<class name="FlowDataMessageImpl" entity-name="FlowDataPer10s" table="FlowDataPer10s">
...
</class>

<class name="FlowDataMessageImpl" entity-name="FlowDataPer20s" table="FlowDataPer20s">
....
</class>
<class name="FlowDataMessageImpl" entity-name="FlowDataPer2m" table="FlowDataPer2m">
...
</class>
```

Here we store the same "Java object" in different tables after we did some roll-up calculations. I would like to map this using JPA (or somebody to tell me it is a bad idea and I should use Hibernate directly like before for this)

Comment: I haven't seen something similar before so I would like to ask: what is the use of such a mapping? If you make a query like `from SoundNotificationWithoutData` you get all all records that have `m_data==null` or you still need to add the restriction in the query? Thanks.

Comment: A class is loaded once, and an EMF can have a single mapping for that class. Obviously you could potentially have 2 EMFs with one mapping for one EMF and one for the other EMF. That is the only situation you could do that. PS This is JPA we are talking about here, not "Spring Data JPA"

Comment: @CristianSevescu The use is that you can either ask for the object from the database with the BLOB (which is an mp3 file) or without the BLOB.

Comment: I have added another example which I think shows what I need more clearly.

Comment: Are you aware of `@SecondaryTable` annotation? http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Tables#Multiple_tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To your first question: you will have to create two Java classes `SoundNotificationWithoutData` and `SoundNotificationWithData`, both classes extending the same third Java class, using the [`@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)`](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Inheritance) and mapped with the [`@Table(name="SoundNotification")`](http://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jpa/Table) annotation. Also notice that you will not be able **in plain JPA** to create a property with a formula (property `m_inUse`), so you will have to use Hibernate-specific stuff OR load that property only when you need it.

To your second problem: again, either use Hibernate-specific stuff, OR use the [@MappedSuperclass](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/MappedSuperclass.html) annotation on the superclass (which is extended by every `FlowDataPer*` classes), without using on it the `@Entity` and `@Inheritance` annotations. Of course you could also use the same solution as for your first question: different classes (`FlowDataPer10s`, `FlowDataPer20s`, ..)  extending a base entity class, anntoated with `@Entity` and `@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)`, but I find it more elegant with the `@MappedSuperclass` annotation.

Comment: For the 2nd problem, moving the data is not an issue, it is the mapping. Would you there also recommend to make different Java classes for each table (all extending the same java class) ?

Comment: Oh, if the entities never change from `FlowDataPer10s` to `FlowDataPer20s`, then of course simply using multiple Java classes extending the same Java class (but with `@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS`)

Comment: Alternatively, for the second problem: you can use the [@MappedSuperclass](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/MappedSuperclass.html) annotation on the superclass, without defining it as an `@Entity` and `@Inheritance`.

Comment: @WimDeblauwe did it work as expected? Any other difficulties on implementation?

Comment: I did not have time to test it yet. I am working with .hbm.xml files, so I will have to see how that works out. I refactered the first problem so it does not exist anymore :) This will not be possible with the 2nd problem, but that is scheduled to be done in 2 weeks or so.